# Listen to DataSource operation and notify listeners in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Imagine that a DataSource field depends on the values of another DataSource. How would each ListGrid that uses that DataSource be automatically notified of any changes? *If possible*, without having to redraw the entire ListGrid but only the affected records?

Consider the following class as the **observer**:

```
public class ObserverDataSource extends DataSource {

    public ObserverDataSource() {
    // This field needs to update/notify every ListGrid that uses 
    // this DataSource when a change occurs in the CountryDataSource.
        DataSourceField countryField = new DataSourceTextField("country", "Country");
        addField(countryField);
        // Other fields...
    }

    public void update() {
    // invalidateCache() doesn't work on its own.
    // What will make each object (ListGrid) that uses the DataSource refresh itself?
    // Even better if it only refreshes the changed records.
    // E.g. now a full redraw of the ListGrid.
    }

}
```

And our **observable** DataSource:

```
public class ObservableDataSource extends DataSource {

    public ObservableDataSource() { 
    DataSourceField idField = new DataSourceIntegerField("id", "Id");
    idField.setPrimaryKey(true);       
    DataSourceField countryField = new DataSourceTextField("country", "Country");
    DataSourceField codeField = new DataSourceIntegerField("code", "Country code");
    setFields(idField, countryField, codeField);
    }

    public executeFetch(...) {
    // Doesn't change anything, don't notify observers.
    // Do logic...
    processResponse(requestId, response);
    }

    public executeAdd(...) {
    // Changed the data, notify the observer (MyDataSource instance).
    // Do logic...
    myDataSourceInstance.update();
    processResponse(requestId, response);
    }

}
```

**Note:** the DataSource template is based on GwtRpcDataSource, which can be [found here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=4814).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, and experimenting, I found out that you can't notify every user of the DataSource that easily. A datasource calls `fireCallback` on each separate listener, when `processResponse` has been called. Alas, I couldn't recreate the functionality, but luckily I found a workaround for the situation:

You need to invalidate the cache of each listener manually. For ListGrid this can be done with `invalidateCache` and but ComboBoxItem with `invalidateDisplayValueCache`. E.g.:

```
public class ObserverDataSource extends DataSource {

    private Set<MyChangeHandler> handlers = new HashSet<MyChangeHandler>();

    public void update() {
        for(MyChangeHandler handler : handlers){
            handler.onChanged(/* Calls invalidateCache on itself */);
        }
    }

}
```

Other possible solutions could be to redraw the entire `ListGrid`, but this is more effecient.